# Embed a VBA function in PHP script or class

Tags: php, cakephp, vba, phpmyadmin

This might sound a little out of the box. But I have a function that wrote previously in VBA and I want to use it a PHP application. I was wondering if I can somehow embed a VBA code in a PHP script or a class??

Comment: Hi did you manage to create a com object or did you rewrite in php? I am curious to know your steps or any references that you may have used as I am faced with task issue at the moment.

Comment: I rewrote the entire module in PHP. It was the easiest to integrate for me into my existing codebase.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd have to rewrite it in PHP or execute it and read the output in to PHP using cURL or fopen.

Answer (score 0):

Script or class is complicated. If you can compile/turn your VBA into a COM component, you can load those, PHP has com support.

Also PHP has support for .net, probably that is more easily possible nowadays:

- [PHP .NET](http://php.net/manual/book.dotnet.php)
- [PHP COM and .Net (Windows)](http://php.net/manual/book.com.php)

If not per function / object, you can always run/exec stuff and you could to input/putput via XML strings or similar so that you create some sort of remove procedure calls.